# How Can I Open a Bootstrap-UI Dropdown with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, protractor, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using angular 1.5, ui-bootstrap 0.14.3, bootstrap 3.2.0 & protractor 3.2.2

I'm trying to use Protractor for e2e testing of an angular/bootstrap-ui application. Demonstrating one of the specs requires the test to open a bootstrap-ui dropdown and click an element contained therein. It's not working - the test link is clicked, but the dropdown never opens (i verified the click by binding an alert to the element's onclick event - the alert popped but Protractor threw an Unexpected Alert Exception...). After trying the approaches mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756953/protractor-e2e-test-wont-click-on-button-in-bootstrap-popover) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843503/protractor-select-from-bootstrap-dropdown), i'm at a loss.

HTML

```
<div dropdown class="dropdown">
    <span>
        <a id="user-link" dropdown-toggle>click me</a>
    </span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/link1">link1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/link2">link2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Protractor spec

```
it('opens the user menu', function () {
    var userLink = element(by.id('user-link'));
    expect(userLink.getInnerHtml()).toEqual('click me');
    userLink.click();
    var link = element(by.css('[href="/link1"]'));
    expect(link.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

As one of links suggests, i've tried using a couple difference variants on `wait()` function with the timeout as high as 20 seconds. I've tried `browser.sleep()` with the same timeout. Neither worked.

It probably goes without saying, but the dropdown opens immediately when it is clicked manually.

Comment: Try adding a blank href to the dropdown-toggle anchor element: <a href></a>

Answer (score 2):

I can share my working code, that is pretty similar to yours:

```
it('should change language between english and spanish', function() {
    //Get dropdown
    var languageSwitcher = element(by.css("div[uib-dropdown]"));

    //Change language to spanish by clicking button with id toSpanish
    languageSwitcher.element(by.id('languageSwitcher')).click();
    languageSwitcher.element(by.id('toSpanish')).click();

    //Some expects about Spanish language

    //Change language to english by clicking button with id toEnglish
    languageSwitcher.element(by.id('languageSwitcher')).click();
    languageSwitcher.element(by.id('toEnglish')).click();

    //Some expects about English language
});
```

And the html code looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right" uib-dropdown keyboard-nav>
    <button id="languageSwitcher" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
        {{"language" | translate}} <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <ul uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="simple-btn-keyboard-nav">
        <li role="menuitem"><a id="toSpanish" href="#" ng-click="changeLanguage('es')">{{"spanish" | translate}}</a></li>
        <li role="menuitem"><a id="toEnglish" href="#" ng-click="changeLanguage('en')">{{"english" | translate}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I added ids to each components to select them easily with `by.id` function.

Comment: helpful post, but why wasn't it chosen as the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but managed to get it working just by adding 'id' to the 'dropdown-toggle'. Until I added the **id="fileMenu"** attribute, it didn't work.

```
  <li  class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <a id="fileMenu" dropdownToggle type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">File<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="new()" href="#">New</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="open()" href="#">Open</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="save()" href="#">Save</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

My project setup:

1. Angular: 5.0.3
2. Protractor: 5.1.2